# Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 - User creation successful but connection with new user fails

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

> ```
> D:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\BIN>sqlplus / as sysdba
> ```
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Oct 30 12:51:12 2014
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release
>   12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
>
> SQL> CREATE USER johndoe IDENTIFIED BY johndoe
>   2  DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
>   3  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";
>
> CREATE USER johndoe IDENTIFIED BY johndoe
>               * ERROR at line 1: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
>
> SQL> alter session set container=PDBORCL;
>
> Session altered.
>
> SQL> CREATE USER johndoe IDENTIFIED BY johndoe
>   2  DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
>   3  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP";
>
> User created.
>
> SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION TO johndoe;
>
> Grant succeeded.
>
> SQL> connect johndoe/johndoe ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid
>   username/password; logon denied
>
> Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE. SQL>

Can Anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

> connect johndoe/johndoe

This is wrong, you need to specify the pluggable database `PDBORCL`.

```
connect johndoe@pdborcl/johndoe
```

Here is a test case to prove,

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> alter session set container=PDBORCL;

Session altered.

SQL> create user test identified by test;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to test;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect test@pdborcl/test;
Connected.
SQL>
```

You can have a look at [Mandatory steps post 12c installation](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/) for common issues post 12c installation.